# Validate Login Errors

Tags: c#, authentication

I am using the following C# code for a Login Page but I get an error that says:

"Please make sure that the username and the password is Correct"

```
 protected void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int Results = 0;
        if (txtUsername.Text != string.Empty && txtPassword.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            Results = Validate_Logon(txtUsername.Text.Trim(), txtPassword.Text.Trim());
            if (Results == 1)
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Login is Good, Send the User to another page or enable controls";
            }
            else
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Invalid Login";
                lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                //Dont Give too much information this might tell a hacker what is wrong in the login    
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Please make sure that the username and the password is Correct";
        }
    }
    public int Validate_Logon(String Username, String Password)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"***************");
        SqlCommand cmdselect = new SqlCommand();
        cmdselect.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmdselect.CommandText = "[dbo].[Log_Members]";
        cmdselect.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 256).Value = Username;
        cmdselect.Parameters.Add("@UPassword", SqlDbType.VarChar, 55).Value = Password;
        cmdselect.Parameters.Add("@OutRes", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
        cmdselect.Parameters["@OutRes"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmdselect.Connection = con;
        int Results = 0;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmdselect.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Results = (int)cmdselect.Parameters["@OutRes"].Value;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            cmdselect.Dispose();
            if (con != null)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        return Results;
    }
```

Please I need to know what is wrong with the code above

Comment: That message gets displayed if `txtUsername` and/or `txtPassword` are equal to `String.empty`

Comment: fyi its a bad idea to store a users password in plain text in the db.

Comment: I am aware, but cannot encrypt them. Any clue?

Comment: Possible problem is that , your Username and Password do not matches with the db. Voila!, enter correct and exact one. That should help

Comment: they are absolutely correct

Answer (score 0):

It is very straightforward:

```
if (txtUsername.Text != string.Empty && txtPassword.Text != string.Empty)
```

This line is returning false, so the `else` executes, which is:

```
else
{
    lblMessage.Text = "Please make sure that the username and the password is Correct";
}
```

Debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, why don't you **check that the you actually entered text into both the username and the password text boxes**?